# SQlite improve query efficiency

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have two tables that are structurally identical and roughly 10k rows each:

```
db1.people         db2.people
***************    ***************
name  |  number    name  |  number
---------------    ---------------
mike  |            bob   |  
john  |            Kev   |  45
mark  |            mark  |  16
***************    ***************
```

my goal is to find the same person in both tables and copy the **number** value from db2 to db1. It took some hacking but i think i have that working:

```
UPDATE people SET number = (SELECT number FROM db2.people WHERE number > 0 AND name = main.people.name);
```

And that works, but its very heavy. I think its doing the following:

- goes through all 10k names in db1.people.names
- finds the same name in db2.people.names
- if db2.people.number is populated it puts the value into main.people.number

the catch is only about 200 of the 10k lines in db2.people are populated with a number.

This is where i am out of my league; how do i limit the above query to only bother running for names that have corresponding number value in db2.people.number?

That should bring my 10k^10k to 200^10k

Thanks,

Comment: Is there some way to put an UPDATE subquery in a SELECT statement for  db2.people WHERE number > 0? the reverse of my current statement: go through db2.people.number and only look at db1.people.name when db2.people.number is populated?

Answer (score 1):

Since SQLite does not support update join syntax, you may be stuck with your current approach involving a correlated subquery.  That being said, if you add indices to the `db2.people` table on both its columns, it may speed up the update noticeably.  If you add an index on `name` and `number` then this would allow a much faster lookup time for each row in `db1.people` during the update.

Answer (score 1):

I read SQLITE supports the exists clause

```
UPDATE people 
SET number = 
(SELECT number FROM db2.people WHERE number > 0 AND name = main.people.name)
where exists 
(SELECT number FROM db2.people WHERE number > 0 AND name = main.people.name);
```

Comment: Thanks Danny, it works great, but i'm surprised to see only about 15% performance improvement?

Comment: Wish I could make 15℅ on my savings.  Awesome.

Comment: I was thinking this might the java  improvement of 2nd run is always faster because everything is in memory.  I hope this isnt the case here.

Comment: I ended up taking a programmatic approach. I read db2 and generate an array of all the names with their corresponding numbers (~200 entries, only the names with populated numbers). From there I then use that list to update db1. The result is over 80% reduction in execution time.