# Is LIMIT OFFSET the best solution for pagination?

Tags: java, sqlite

**Explanation:**

I am creating a invoicing system with SQLite.
The Database's tables include: customers and invoices.
Each invoiceOBJ(14 columns of data) contains a customerOBJ(4 columns of data),
while each invoiceOBJ will contain a customerID to retrieve the corresponding customer.

I randomly generated 1 million records in the invoices table,
from my understanding and [research (outDated?)](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/SQLite-performance-for-10-Million-Records-td11019.html)  1 million records is slightly pushing it for  sqlite (performance wise)

My query for loading the invoices into a javaFX table view is

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(String.format("SELECT id,year,vin,carModel,condition,licenseState,regNum,stage,vehicleID,paintCode,dateOfInvoice," +
                "bodyStyle,manufacturer, customerID  FROM invoices LIMIT 100  OFFSET (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM invoices)-%d", indexStart));
```

indexStart is the number to page over the invoices through the gui either -100, or +100.

What I  am wondering **if this is the best solution** with sqlite
as each time the user decides to go the the next page, with 1 million invoices/records this takes 250-264ms on average. Then each query to get the customerOBJ when making the invoiceOBJ is 0.6-1ms on average*100(Limit), which totals to usually around 300 ms for each iteration.

Realistically, 1 million invoices is 98% over kill for what it is needed  for, but, for educational purposes I am trying to make it as efficient as possible.

Just to clarify, I am not asking if this sqlite is the best way to do this, but if this is the best way in sqlite to do this.

**sqlitedb Object , relevant methods:**

```
 public void connect() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:school.sqlite");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public ArrayList<invoiceOBJ> listInvoices(int indexStart) {
        //invoiceAmount  = invoices to index.
        ArrayList<invoiceOBJ> invoices = new ArrayList<>();
        //System.out.println(indexStart + "index start");
        try {
            connect();
            stmt = c.createStatement();
            stmt.setFetchSize(100);

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(String.format("SELECT id,year,vin,carModel,condition,licenseState,regNum,stage,vehicleID,paintCode,dateOfInvoice," +
                    "bodyStyle,manufacturer, customerID  FROM invoices LIMIT 100  OFFSET (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM invoices)-%d", indexStart));

            int id;
            String customerID;
            String year;
            String vin;
            String carModel;
            String condition;
            String licenseState;
            String regNum;
            String stage;
            String vehicleID;
            String paintCode;
            String dateOfInvoice;
            String bodyStyle;
            String manufacturer;
            c.setAutoCommit(false);

            while (rs.next()) {


                id = rs.getInt(1);
                year = rs.getString(2);
                vin = rs.getString(3);
                carModel = rs.getString(4);
                condition = rs.getString(5);
                licenseState = rs.getString(6);
                regNum = rs.getString(7);
                stage = rs.getString(8);
                vehicleID = rs.getString(9);
                paintCode = rs.getString(10);
                dateOfInvoice = rs.getString(11);
                bodyStyle = rs.getString(12);
                manufacturer = rs.getString(13);
                customerID = rs.getString(14);


//                System.out.println(String.format("ID: %d , CustomerID: %s Year: %s, Vin: %s, \ncarModel %s, condition: %s, licenseState: %s \n" +
//                                "regNum: %s, stage: %s vehicleID: %s, paintCode: %s, dateOfInvoice: %s, bodyStyle:%s", id, customerID, year, vin, carModel
//                        , condition, licenseState, regNum, stage, vehicleID, paintCode, dateOfInvoice, bodyStyle));


                //add to invoice list.

                invoices.add(new invoiceOBJ(id,
                        carModel, manufacturer,
                        vin, condition, licenseState,
                        regNum, stage, vehicleID, paintCode,
                        bodyStyle, year, dateOfInvoice, findCustomer(customerID)));


                // System.out.println("added A customer");


            }
            stmt.close();
            rs.close();
            c.close();
            //System.out.println("load complete..");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);

        return invoices;

    }

    public HashMap<String, String> findCustomer(String id) {

        String sql = String.format("SELECT firstName, lastName,id, date FROM customers WHERE id=%s", id);
        HashMap<String, String> customerData = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
            ResultSet data = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            customerData.put("firstName", data.getString(1));
            customerData.put("lastName", data.getString(2));
            customerData.put("date", data.getString(4));
            customerData.put("id", data.getString(3));
            stmt.close();
            data.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return customerData;
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        try {
            c.close();
            stmt.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

P.S This is my first attempt and  the first time I have used SQL  so any  extra explanation would be appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT:
Some of the resources I have already read from as well:

[SQlite improve query efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41939471/sqlite-improve-query-efficiency)

[SQLite storage class And retrieval efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43183503/sqlite-storage-class-and-retrieval-efficiency)

[Faster Pagination in Mysql – Why Order By With Limit and Offset is Slow?](https://www.eversql.com/faster-pagination-in-mysql-why-order-by-with-limit-and-offset-is-slow/)

No Idea if these are  good / relevant, just for extra detail.

And functionality in images:

https://imgur.com/a/pczeCSO : before

https://imgur.com/a/kZT3l9C : +100 more/next invoices.

Comment: The best way is to save the last rowid displayed and then select rows greater than it with the appropriate order by and limit clauses.

Comment: Good discussion on the topic: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results

Comment: very much so! I found using  "WHERE id between min max" is 228 ms faster!